# Powershell - Detect changes to Proxy settings

Tags: powershell, proxy

I’m researching the capabilities of powershell for a work related task.

Our browsers proxy settings change at an unknown possibly random interval.

The change disables all softwares connection to the internet.

Is there a way to automatically detect when a change to the proxy settings has occurred? Then reset the proxy to blank.

Thanks!

Comment: But why does it just randomly change

Comment: Its better to enforce your proxy settings through policies.

Comment: I expect it's "changing randomly" because you already have a policy enforced which is changing it when Group Policy refreshes. Ask your Domain administrator to enforce the correct policy for your use.

Comment: Our server is being migrated by our Group IT staff. They will not answer or tackle non critical issues. Hence why I’m searching for alternative solutions.